# Components of a Test Plan document?

Tags: test-management, test-planning, test-strategy

What are the most important components/parts of a well-written test plan document for a testing project. Consider you are testing a Financial web app.

Is test plan a part of overall test strategy document? Are the 2 documents merged in commercial testing projects.

Please provide a real world, test plan document , if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a test plan](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/how-to-write-a-test-plan)

Answer (score 8):

> What are the most important components/parts of a well-written test plan document for a testing project. Consider you are testing a Financial web app.

As per IEEE 829 standards, the components of a Test Plan document should be :

- Test Plan identifier
- References
- Introduction
- Test Items
- Risks
- Items to be tested
- Features excluded for testing
- Testing Approach
- Test Pass and Fail Criteria
- Resumption/Suspension Criteria
- Test deliverables
- Test Environment Set Up
- Training and Staffing
- Team Member Responsibilities
- Testing Schedule
- Planning for Risks and Contingency Plans
- Approvals

You can read in detail about this here : [IEEE 829](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/study/courses/ITS/public/ieee829.html)

However it is not mandatory to include each and every thing mentioned here. I have seen many test plans missing many components from this check list. In commercial companies ( like MNC's) , there is a specified custom format, which is roughly based on these standards ( or any standard that the company follows).

> Is test plan a part of overall test strategy document? Are the 2 documents merged in commercial testing projects.

A test strategy defines the overall testing approach to be followed during the testing and as such, it should be a different document, a high level definition of the testing that we are going to follow. However, it is not an unfamiliar situation, when test strategy is defined inside the test plan itself ( a practice in my current organization).

Since we are talking about an overall strategy here, so Test Plan would be an essential part of a test strategy. You can have a single high level Test Strategy document for a project and then have various test plans, which are created as per the test strategy.

A very good documented example would be [this](http://www.testingexcellence.com/test-strategy-and-test-plan/).

> Please provide a real world, test plan document , if possible.

You will find a lot of such test plans on internet. A good place would be [this](http://www.coleyconsulting.co.uk/testplan.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Below are the components of a test plan, which should be included.
1. **Summary**

1.1. **Introduction** - Provide an overview of this document in this section

1.2. **Scope of testing** - The scope of testing needs to be clearly defined. The plan should define items / features that are in scope or out of scope for the testing phase.

```
- 1.2.1. **Features To be tested** - All features/use cases which are to be tested

- 1.2.2. **Features Not to be tested** - All features which are not to be tested

- 1.2.3. **References** - SRS, BRD, FRS references used for the scope
```

1.3. **Milestones** - List down all the minor and major milestones along with planned start and end dates

1.4. **Deliverables** - List down all the deliverables from the testing phase along with their acceptance criteria

2. **Resources** - Mention all the physical and non-physical resources that will be used

   2.1. **Hardware** - List down the hardware requirements for the testing phase

   2.2. **Environment details** - Provide a list of the various environments that will be used for the testing phase along with their purpose and configuration details.

   2.3. **Testing tools** - Provide a list of the tools that are required for this phase.

   2.4. **Team composition** - List down the names of the team members who will be involved in the testing phase, along with their roles and responsibilities

   2.5. **Training Requirements** - If any skill set or training is required
3. **Test Strategy** - Describe the testing strategy which will be followed in the project. Also, define the different types testing.

   3.1. **Types of testing** - List out different types of testing that will be conducted in the testing phase. Elaborate the different testing specifications given by the customer and provide details on how different types of testing would be conducted

   3.2. **Entry and Exit Criteria** - Write down the entry and exit criteria of the testing phase i.e. when you will start testing and when you stop testing.

   3.3. **Suspension and Resumption Criteria** - Use this section to write down the suspension and Resumption during the testing phase.

   3.4. **System Acceptance Criteria** - Use this section to describe the system acceptance criteria based on which the project acceptance will be received
4. **Test Planning**

   4.1. **Test Schedule** - Use this section to document the detailed test plan. This would include a detailed work breakdown structure (WBS) of all activities related to testing along with resources.

   4.2. **Test Design** - Use this section to document the procedure for preparing test cases. Explain the various fields of the test cases. Expand this section to include the process for review and approval of test cases and how the documents will be shared among stakeholders.

   4.3. **Test Execution** - Use this section to detail the process that will be followed for testing - how testing would be conducted, and how testing results would be captured and shared.
5. **Bug Tracking Process** - Use this section to describe the process for recording bugs found during the various testing cycles and the workflow for tracking these bugs to closure. This section would also provide details as per the sections below.

   5.1. **Bug tracking tool** - Detail about the tool being used for defect logging and tracking

   5.2. **Bug reporting** - Provide details of the various fields against which information needs to be entered while reporting a bug.

   5.3. **Bug lifecycle** - For example: New/raised --> open/assigned --> resolved/fixed --> closed/verified. Also, specify who will be responsible for conducting triage meetings and how any conflicts will be resolved.
6. **NFRs Testing** - Use this section to define plan for the Non-functional testing like Performance, Security, Usability etc.

   6.1. **Tools used for NFRs** - name of the tools

   6.2. **NFR Goals** - Mention all the goals for performance testing for Response time, Throughput etc.
7. **Risk Management** - Use this section for documenting the risks involved in testing and their Mitigation plan. Assign priority and impact to all risks.
8. **Reporting and Communication Plan** - Write down the reporting and communication plan for the testing phase. Identify Key contact personnel from both on-site and off-shore teams and representatives from the client side.
9. **Measurement Plan** - List down the metrics that will be used to track the progress of the testing phase and assess whether the objectives of this phase have been met or not. Like Defect Leakage, Defect Removal Efficiency etc.
10. **Assumptions and Dependencies** - List out the assumptions and dependencies associated with this phase and any risks that may exist pertaining to these.
11. **Appendix** - Use this section to provide expansion of abbreviation and attach reference documents and templates

**Is test plan a part of overall test strategy document?**

Test Plan and Test Strategy can be separate documents and sometimes they are merged together. This all depends upon the person creating these documents and scope of the application. If project is bigger in size and a complete testing project then it make sense to have different documents, else create a single document for both. [Difference](http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/9651-test-strategy-vs-test-plan.html) in Test plan and Test strategy document.

These are the simple steps to be taken care of for creating a [Test Strategy](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/writing-test-strategy-document-template/) document.

Refer this link for the test plan [samples and components.](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-plan-sample-softwaretesting-and-quality-assurance-templates/)